# How to scale a .svg being the background in a div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have used a div-Container to insert a logo in it like this:

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

The css looks like this:

```
#logo {
    width: 333px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("../img/logo1.png");
    background-image: url("../img/logo0.svg"); 
}
```

However, when I try to rezise #logo (for example for devices with smaller screens), it does not resize the image being the background and the image is cut at the edges.

My question is: How to scale the .svg-image while the div-container is scaling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `background-size: contain;`

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

> **contain**
>
> A keyword that scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). Image is letterboxed within the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the empty areas (either top/bottom of left/right) are filled with the background-color.  The image is automatically centered unless over-ridden by another property such as background-position.

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:url(http://kompozer.sourceforge.net/images/logo/kpz08-chinon.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
}
```